# Extract data format from string

Tags: r

Can someone tell me how I extract the date from the sentence below:

`head(df)`, result:

```
 X..Indicadores...APM...Aplicacoes_e_Transacoes...PlainText
1                        # Application: Central Analysis Server
2                                       # Application Id: CVENT
3          # Data View: Application, transaction, and tier data
4                                          # Data View Id: Tier
5              # Filters: Tier=LAN | WAN | Enterprise Synthetic
6                             # 22/01/17 00:00 - 23/01/17 00:00
```

I only need the first date, in 6º line:

22/01/17

Can someone help me

Comment: That is a weirdly structured sentence... Do all sentences take 6 rows?

Comment: Could you show the expected output?

Comment: What exactly is the rule for extraction here? So you have many different data.frames? Are there many different rows you want to process? How do you know what data to extract? Is it digit-digit-slash-digit-digit-slash-digit-digit? Is it always in the 6th row?

Comment: What exactly is the rule for extraction here?
I need to extract the date "01/22/17".

So you have many different data.frames?
Only one. 

Are there many different rows that you want to process?
Always the 6th row of the data frame. I create the data frame, extract it and then delete the data frame.

How do you know what data to extract?
By format maybe, grep -> "*/*/* *:*"

Is it digit-digit-slash-digit-digit-slash-digit-digit?
Yes

Is it always in the 6th row?
Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.frame(
  `X..Indicadores...APM...Aplicacoes_e_Transacoes...PlainText`=
  c("# Application: Central Analysis Server",
    "# Application Id: CVENT", 
    "# Data View: Application, transaction, and tier data", 
    "# Data View Id: Tier", 
    "# Filters: Tier=LAN | WAN | Enterprise Synthetic", 
    "# 22/01/17 00:00 - 23/01/17 00:00"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> df

library(stringi)

stri_extract_first_regex(df[6,1], "([[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+)")
## [1] "22/01/17"
```

Comment: Thanks hrbmstr !!